# Adding a button with the SubmitForm Function with PDFBOX in Java

Tags: java, pdf, pdfbox

***Update**: I managed to get it working. I set up a small virtuel server just to catch if the submit button is doing anything and it seems to work. Although for some reason the button is not visible when I open the PDF with Adobe Reader, but it is there and works. In an browser it shows normally. I updated the code with the now working code.

I have multiple PDF´s with fillable form fields. Now I want to automatically add a button to the PDF´s, which when pressed should submit the new and filled PDF´s. When this is working it will run on a server, but for now I just need the submit button working.

This functionallity already exists in Adobe Acrobat Pro DC ("Add a submit button", https://helpx.adobe.com/acrobat/using/setting-action-buttons-pdf-forms.html).But I would need to do this with a lot of PDF´s so I want to automate it and I would need to buy the expensive license. The best possible way I could find is using the Java library PDFBOX (https://pdfbox.apache.org/index.html). But I´m kinda stuck with the adding of the Action to the Button.

This is my Code, instead of importing a PDF you could just create a new, empty one. The important thing is the submit button:

```java
public static void main(String[] args)
  {
    try
    {
      PDDocument pdf = PDDocument.load(inputFile);
      PDAcroForm acro = pdf.getDocumentCatalog().getAcroForm();

      COSDictionary cosDict1 = new COSDictionary();
      COSArray buttonRect1 = new COSArray();
      buttonRect1.add(new COSFloat(35)); // x1
      buttonRect1.add(new COSFloat(10)); // y1
      buttonRect1.add(new COSFloat(105)); // x2
      buttonRect1.add(new COSFloat(30)); // y2

      cosDict1.setItem(COSName.RECT, buttonRect1);
      cosDict1.setItem(COSName.FT, COSName.getPDFName("Btn")); // Field
      // Type
      cosDict1.setItem(COSName.TYPE, COSName.ANNOT);
      cosDict1.setItem(COSName.SUBTYPE, COSName.getPDFName("Widget"));
      cosDict1.setItem(COSName.T, new COSString("submit"));
      cosDict1.setItem(COSName.DA, new COSString("/F0 6 Tf 0 g 1 1 1 rg "));

      PDPushButton button = new PDPushButton(acro);

      button.getCOSObject().addAll(cosDict1);
      acro.getFields().add(button);

      PDAnnotationWidget widget = button.getWidgets().get(0);

      PDAppearanceCharacteristicsDictionary buttonFieldAppearance = new 
      PDAppearanceCharacteristicsDictionary(
        new COSDictionary());
      COSArray borderColorArray = new COSArray();
      borderColorArray.add(new COSFloat((float)(141f / 255f)));
      borderColorArray.add(new COSFloat((float)(179f / 255f)));
      borderColorArray.add(new COSFloat((float)(226f / 255f)));
      PDColor blue = new PDColor(borderColorArray, PDDeviceRGB.INSTANCE);
      buttonFieldAppearance.setBorderColour(blue);
      buttonFieldAppearance.setBackground(blue);
      buttonFieldAppearance.setNormalCaption("Submit");
      widget.setAppearanceCharacteristics(buttonFieldAppearance);

      pdf.save(outputFile);
      pdf.close();
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
      e.printStackTrace();
      System.err.println(e.getLocalizedMessage());
    }
  }
```

Even after reading through parts of the API of PDFBOX (https://pdfbox.apache.org/docs/2.0.13/javadocs/) I´m still confused how I´m supposed to do that. I tried reverse engineering a PDF form with a working submit button I created with test version of Adobe Acrobat Pro DC. Which made it a bit clearer but I still dont fully get it. I noticed that it´s doing something with the COSDictonarys so I added the following code which handles the action of the button:

```java
      PDActionSubmitForm submitForm = new PDActionSubmitForm();
      widget.setAction(submitForm);

      COSDictionary cosDic = new COSDictionary();
      COSDictionary cosURIDic = new COSDictionary();
      cosURIDic.setItem(COSName.F, new COSString("http://localhost:80/cgi- 
      bin/myscript#FDF"));
      cosURIDic.setItem(COSName.FILESPEC, COSName.URI);
       cosDic.setItem(COSName.F, cosURIDic);
      cosDic.setItem(COSName.S, COSName.getPDFName("SubmitForm"));
      COSDictionary buttonCOSDic = new COSDictionary(cosDic);

      widget.getAction().getCOSObject().addAll(buttonCOSDic);

      pdf.getPage(0).getAnnotations().add(widget);
      button.getWidgets().add(widget);
```

And this is what I used to try to reverse engineer what Adobe Acrobat Pro DC does:

```
public static void main(String[] args)
  {
    try
    {
      PDDocument pdf = PDDocument.load(inputFile);
      PDAcroForm acro = pdf.getDocumentCatalog().getAcroForm();

      List<PDField> acroFields = acro.getFields();
      for (PDField pdField : acroFields)
      {
        if (pdField.getFullyQualifiedName().toLowerCase().contains("submit"))
        {
          try
          {
            System.out.println("FieldType: " + pdField.getFieldType());
            // System.out.println("Actions: " + pdField.getActions().toString()); //NullPointer
            System.out.println("Widgets: " + pdField.getWidgets().toString());
            List<PDAnnotationWidget> listWidgets = pdField.getWidgets();
            for (PDAnnotationWidget pdAnnotationWidget : listWidgets)
            {
              System.out.println("PDAction: " + pdAnnotationWidget.getAction());
              System.out
                .println("PDActionCOSObject: " + pdAnnotationWidget.getAction().getCOSObject());
            }
          }
          catch (Exception e)
          {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
            System.err.println(e.getLocalizedMessage());
          }
        }
      }
      System.out.println("end");
    }
    catch (IOException e)
    {
      // TODO Auto-generated catch block
      e.printStackTrace();
    }
  }
```

which prints:

```
FieldType: Btn
Widgets: [org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.interactive.annotation.PDAnnotationWidget@156643d4]
PDAction: org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.interactive.action.PDActionSubmitForm@200a570f
PDActionCOSObject: COSDictionary{COSName{F}:COSDictionary{COSName{F}:COSString{http://localhost:80/cgi-bin/myscript#FDF};COSName{FS}:COSName{URL};};COSName{S}:COSName{SubmitForm};}
```

So I will keep trying to find a solution, but maybe some of you already know the answer and can help me out. Hope I included everything you may need to help me.

Comment: The best would be to link to a model file and to your file. One could then look at both with PDFDebugger to see where the difference is.